# setuptools not able to upgrade or degrade in python 3.5

Tags: python

I am trying to upgrade/degrade `setuptools` from 19.6.2 to 20.9.

I used workaround `--ignore-installed` to install the new version of `setuptools`.

It got successfully installed, but I can still find the `setuptools-19.6.2-py3.5.egg` file in `site-package` path of python.
I am trying to convert my python script into `.exe`. When I am trying to run the `.exe` it crashes giving the below error.:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\rthooks\pyi_rth_pkgres.py", line 11, in
 <module>
  `File "c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py"
, line 389, in load_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\setuptools-19.6.2-py3.5.egg\pkg_resources\__init__.py", li
ne 75, in <module>
  File "site-packages\setuptools-19.6.2-py3.5.egg\pkg_resources\extern\__init__.
py", line 60, in load_module
ImportError: The 'packaging' package is required; normally this is bundled with
this package so if you get this warning, consult the packager of your distributi
on.
Failed to execute script pyi_rth_pkgres
```

`PyInstaller` is still taking up the previous version of `setuptools`.
Please help if somebody has come across this issue.